# Remove symbol link

Tags: terminal, command-line, symlink

In terminal, I have made a **symbol link** like following:

```
ln -s ../../../../ jni/prod
```

It symbol links `prod` **directory** (which is 4 levels up from current location) to `jni/prod` .

I'd like to emphasize that it symbol links a **directory** NOT a **file**.

Now, I want to remove this symlink, how to do it?

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: And more importantly, if you don't describe what you "don't get" then people have to guess. Hopefully my guess as to what you don't get about symlinks was correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you find yourself confused about where a file really exists, cd to the directory you expect and use `rm -i` and refrain from adding any path - delete the file in the current directory. Also, in unix, everything is a file - including a directory. You do have saving grace that trying to delete a file that looks like a directory will pause unless you are recursively deleting files.

Worst case, you could use `ls -lai` to inspect the inode numbers to be sure a file is really symlinked and not hard linked.

If that doesn't help, make a temp directory and play with links:

```
touch foo
ln foo bar       # hard link
ln -s foo baz    # sym link
ls -lai
rm foo
ls -lai
```

At this point, you have the hard link file bar left and a sym link to the missing "foo" file. Since in your case, the link is in a different directory than the target, you shouldn't have too much problem deleting the item you wish.

Answer (score 0):

A symbolic link is a file even if the link is to a directory.  So if you simply did an `rm` that will get rid of the link:

```
rm jni/prod
```